# Make a recursive ruby function

Tags: ruby, function, recursion

Make a RECURSIVE ruby function "double_fact(n)" defined as follows – 
                 n!! = 1 if n = −1 or n = 0 or n = 1; 
                          n(n − 2)!! otherwise. 
     Outputs the result of double_fact() respecting to a value specified
     from the command line.

```
      //Hint: Ruby has the usual "and", "or" and "not" operators. You may  
        need "or" to test multiple conditions here. Also, doublefact(8) = 384.
```

Comment: Include what you have attempted so far. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Is it your homework?

Comment: Hint: Do not use `and` and `or` with conditionals. They are for control flow.

Comment: I hate to be that guy just asking for answers, but I have no idea how to even get started with this problem. Any help would be awesome, if you don't want to, you don't need to give me the entire answer

Comment: Do you understand the math broken down into steps?  I'm not familiar with your use of `!!` used after anything.  Could you write it out in English rather then psuedo-not-ruby-code?

Comment: @6ftDan: While this *is* a very bad question, the definition of "double factorial" (!!) is right there in the question: n!! = 1 if n ∈ [-1..1], 2*(n-2)!! otherwise.

Comment: Forgive me for not studying calculus.

Answer (score 1):

The problem statement is very misleading. You don't need any boolean operators at all, you can just translate the mathematical definition 1:1 into Ruby:

```
def doublefact(n)
  return 1 if (-1..1).include?(n)
  n * doublefact(n-2)
end
```